# dispatching mouse events to HTMLLoader in Adobe AIR Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

This is my first post on here because I really need help understanding the fundamental communication between Actionscript events and HTML events. I am currently using a clear MovieClip placed on top of a HTMLLoader object. This movieclip shares the same x,y,w,h and is currently allowing me to scroll the HTMLLoader object by dragging anywhere on the screen (i am making a browser for a touch screen app). How can I dispatch a mouseevent to the HTMLLoader object. I am pretty good at injecting javascript into the HTML content within the HTMLLoader and I am familiar

Comment: Well it appears your question drifted off into the ether at the end there.  Also I'm not sure you're going about this the "right" way, if you're using AIR for export to mobile devices it generally handles the changes in interactivity and control sizes based on the framwork UI components.  Anyhow my opinion aside if you have an object with id htmlLoader you can call htmlLoader.dispatchEvent(new Event("doSomething")) any UIComponent implementing IEventDispatcher can have dispatchEvent called on it.

Comment: Why do you place MovieClip on top of HTMLLoader?

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears your question drifted off into the ether at the end there.  Also I'm not sure you're going about this the "right" way, if you're using AIR for export to mobile devices it generally handles the changes in interactivity and control sizes based on the framwork UI components.  Anyhow my opinion aside if you have an object with id htmlLoader you can call htmlLoader.dispatchEvent(new Event("doSomething")) any UIComponent implementing IEventDispatcher can have dispatchEvent called on it.